# Download only the header of binary files from an FTP

Tags: curl, download, ftp, wget

I have access to a public ftp server that contains several thousands of large binary file. I'm able to download all the files of a given folder with `wget` but this is time consuming and takes a lot of space on my disk. I actually only need to get the header of each file (the first 380 bytes). The header of the file contains metadata that will enable me to cherry-pick the files I need. The rest of the files is "only" the payload.

I would like to download very quickly, with `wget` or `curl` (or any other way) the first 380 bytes of each file from this server. According to this [Q](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121314/download-only-a-part-of-a-file) I tried to download a single file:

```
curl --header "Range: bytes=0-380" ftp://url/file.ext --output test.ext
```

But this actually downloads the whole file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`curl` has [`--range`/`-r` switch](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-r), which is documented to support even FTP protocol:

```
curl --range 0-380 ftp://example.com/file.ext --output test.ext
```

---

Regarding your attempt with `--header:`
FTP protocol has no headers. `--header` switch is for HTTP only.

`wget` does not seem to support ranges with FTP protocol.